# TortoiseGitでメールアドレスが設定出来ない

Tags: git, windows-10, tortoisegit

gitを使用するために、TortoiseGitをインストールしましたが、設定が上手く行きません。
デスクトップで右クリックから、TortoiseGitの設定画面を開き、Gitを選択、名前の入力までは出来ましたが、メールアドレスが入力出来ません。
そのまま設定画面を閉じてcommitしようとしてもメールアドレスが設定されてないとエラーが出ます。

環境はWindows10 Homeです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: TortoiseGit再インストールしたらうまくいきました本当にありがとう御座います

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 編集対象の選択

設定画面の上部に「設定のでどころ（Config source）」という選択項目があります。
ここで、編集する対象を適切に選ぶ必要があります。

- 「ローカル（Local）」がプロジェクトディレクトリの`.git/config` に
- 「グローバル（Global）」が ユーザーのホームディレクトリの `.gitconfig` に
- 「システム（System）」がシステム共通の設定である `/etc/gitconfig` に
- 「有効値（Effective）」はそれらを優先度順に読み込んだ結果として決定された値（つまり編集する物ではない）に

対応しています。

プロジェクト間で共通のメールアドレスを設定する、という事でしたら「グローバル」です。
このプロジェクト（ディレクトリ）にだけ設定したい、という事ならば「ローカル」です。

#### インストール時の設定

質問者さんが再インストールで解決したのは、インストール時にユーザ情報を聞かれた際に、設定ファイルに反映するチェック欄を有効にしたためと思われます。
ここでこの選択をすると、入力したユーザ情報は「グローバル」、つまりユーザーのホームディレクトリの`.gitconfig` に書き込まれます。
ですから、後からこれを変更する場合は「グローバル」を選択し、編集する事になります。